# Two Component with the same name - define priority

Tags: .net-core, multi-tenant, blazor

I am working on a multitenancy system in a .NET Core 3.1 project. The idea is that I'll have a default Blazor App with all it's components and razor pages. And then be able to use custom components and pages if domain is ABC.com instead of DEFAULT.com.

I've already resolved the routing in this case with writing a custom router in blazor. My issue is that my blazor core app has two components in these locations:

- Pages/Components/Header.razor
- Pages/Components/Footer.razor.

and I've got a Pages/Index.razor that looks something like this:

```
@page ""
@using @MyApp.Pages.Components

<div class="page-wrap">
 <Header></Header>
   <div>This is the homepage.</div>
 <Footer></Header>
</div>
```

now what I am trying todo is something like this:
I've got a file in a different location at say, Tenants/test/Pages/Index.razor with the following code:

```
@page ""
@using @MyApp.Pages.Components
@using @MyApp.Pages.Components
@using @MyApp.Tenants.Pages.Components

<div class="page-wrap">
 <Header></Header>
   <div>This is the child websites homepage.</div>
 <Footer></Header>
</div>
```

the issue with this is that Blazor can't figure out if to use `MyApp.Pages.Components.Header` or `MyApp.Tenants.Pages.Components.Header`. Is there a way to tell it to use the blazor component from the specific folder (default) unless we have a Header.razor class somewhere else, like in Tenants?

I know that razor files get compiled into actual classes, and that is mostly what breaks my code, since it can't figure out which component should be rendered there. Is there a way to overload default blazor behaviour for this?

Comment: If all tenants have custom components, why not just prefix them with the tenant name? i.e. `ABC-Header` and `ABC-Footer`